# Is it possible to get stack trace in Google Apps Script V8

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to build custom error/warning handler which will send me an email when some special asserts fail, simple class

```
function MailError(message, context){
    MailApp.sendEmail(...
}
```

so I can check what's wrong there. Would be very nice to also put stack trace there, so I can see exact line where it happened, and I won't have to pass some mark about this every time in second *context* parameter.

In javascript, we can get stack trace by using *console.log*, e.g.

```
(function tracer() { console.trace()}) ()
```

would produce something like

```
console.trace
tracer @ js:12
```

in apps script, that would give

```
Exception: ScriptError TypeError: console.trace is not a function
```

because, apparently, it's not implemented. Also, it prints on console, while I need it in variable to email it to me.

Any way to get stack trace in variable, in V8 runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Found some workaround using throw/catch, looks a bit strange, but seem to work fine

```
function MailError(message){
    try {
        throw new Error(message)
    } catch(e) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(MY_EMAIL, "[Error] " + message, e.stack)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
//with some formatting and indentation
//strip off the first few lines using .splice(n) after split
const __getStackTrace__ = function(message) {
  let s = `Error: ${message}\n`;
  (new Error()).stack
               .split('\n')
               .forEach((token)=>
               {s += `\t${token.trim()}\n`}
  );      
  return s;
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).